# CryptoJS in separate API

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, cryptojs

In a chat application can I call encryption while sending the message(/sendMessage) to DB in one API and while retrieving that message(/viewMessage) through another API can I do decryption? The database I was using is MongoDB and for backend its Express JS. If so can anyone give me an idea, please? Sorry if my question was stupid I just started learning.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.